# How to get true positive, false negative table from output of predict()?

Tags: r

I would like to print simple table which will show how much rows in test set were predicted right and how much were wrong (true-negative, false-positive).

```
      |  class1   |   class2  |
class1|0.577995490|0.686545476|
class2|0.885664669|0.559988874|
```

(values in this table are not real)

I am currently using klaR package and NaiveBayes function which i use in predict() function. It looks like this:

```
prediction <- predict(naiveBayesSet, testSet)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `table` function in the base package to do something like this:

```
table(Predictions = prediction, TrueLabels = Labels)
```

where prediction is the the vector from your code above and Labels is a vector with the true labels in it.

Alternatively the function `errormatrix()` in the package `klaR` that you're already using can do this.

Answer (score 3):

The `caret` package has a function called `confusionMatrix` for this purpose:

```
require(caret)

confusionMatrix(prediction, reference)
```

Comment: the two arguments have to be factors for this to work